# What can I do to fix my variables not being changed in Android?

Tags: android, variables

```
package org.example.mbtiapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MBTITest extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener   {

    int I, E, N, S, T, F, J, P;
    String[] type;
    ArrayList<String> Evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    Spinner firstSpinner ;
    Spinner secondSpinner ;
    Spinner thirdSpinner;
    Spinner fourthSpinner ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        I = 0;
        E = 0;
        N = 0;
        S = 0;
        T = 0;
        F = 0;
        J = 0;
        P = 0;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mbtitest);
        firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        secondSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        thirdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        fourthSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        type = new String[4];
        addItemsOnSpinner1();
        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addItemsOnSpinner3();
        addItemsOnSpinner4();
        Evaluator.add("");
        Evaluator.add("");
        Evaluator.add("");
        Evaluator.add("");
        final Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getPersonality();
                evaluateType();
                StringBuilder typeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String letters : type) {
                    typeBuilder.append(letters);
                }
                TextView calculatedPersonality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.personalitytype);
                calculatedPersonality.setText(typeBuilder.toString());

            }
        });


        }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner1(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner2(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner3(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner4(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch (arg1.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            String firstAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(0);
            Evaluator.add(0 ,firstAnswer.toString());
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            String secondAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(1);
            Evaluator.add(1, secondAnswer.toString());
            break;
        case R.id.spinner3:
            String thirdAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(2);
            Evaluator.add(2, thirdAnswer.toString());
            break;
        case R.id.spinner4:
            String fourthAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(3);
            Evaluator.add(3, fourthAnswer.toString());
            break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    //Evaluates answers 
    public void getPersonality(){
        if (Evaluator.get(0).equals(R.string.True)){
            E = E + 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(0).equals(R.string.IntheMiddle)){
            E = E + 1;
            I = I + 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(0).equals(R.string.False)){
            I = I + 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "True"){
            N += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "In the Middle"){
            N += 1;
            S += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "False"){
            S += 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "True"){
            F += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "In the Middle"){
            F += 1;
            T += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "False"){
            T += 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "True"){
            P += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "In the Middle"){
            P += 1;
            J += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "False"){
            J += 1;
        }

    }

    public void evaluateType(){
        //INTRO VS EXTRO
        if (E > I){
            type[0] = "E";  
        }
        if (I > E){
            type[0] = "I";
        }
        if (I == E){
            type[0] = "X";      
        }
        //INTUITION VS SENSING
        if (N > S){
            type[1] = "N";  
        }
        if (S > N){
            type[1] = "S";
        }
        if (S == N){
            type[1] = "x";      
        }
        //THINKING VS FEELING
        if (T > F){
            type[2] = "T";  
        }
        if (F > T){
            type[2] = "F";
        }
        if (T == F){
            type[2] = "x";      
        }
        //JUDGING VS PERCIEVING
        if (J > P){
            type[3] = "J";  
        }
        if (P > J){
            type[3] = "P";
        }
        if (P == J){
            type[3] = "x";      
        }

    }











}
```

As you can see here, my text view is returning Xxxx.  I have tried various ways to get it to respond but I am pretty sure my problem lies in my getPersonality() method.  What can I do to allow my evaluateType() method to display E, or I instead of x?  I am a noobie, sorry.
Edit: To clarify.  I'd like my type variable, to display E X or I depending on what Spinner item was selected.

Comment: `R.string.True` is an integer that represents the id of a string. `firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` is a String. it does not make any sense to compare those. you'd know if you had taken the time to run your code step by step before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of code to go through and try to debug in a post. You need to follow the code and see where it seems to get messed up. However, I did notice one thing that could be causing your issue from a quick glance. In your `onItemSelected()` you are comparing the wrong `View` to your `Spinner` `id`s. The second param is the `TextView` which displays the `Spinner` items. You want to compare your first param. Also, you may want to change your params to something meaningful. Here is what I mean

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){  // here use parent
    case R.id.spinner1:
        String firstAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Evaluator.remove(0);
        Evaluator.add(0 ,firstAnswer.toString());
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        String secondAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Evaluator.remove(1);
        Evaluator.add(1, secondAnswer.toString());
        break;
```

As A--C pointed out, you are comparing `Strings` wrong here

```
if (Evaluator.get(1) == "In the Middle")
```

`.equals()` is correct because that compares the value where `==` compares the objects they reference. Also, as pointed out in a comment above by njzk2, `R.string.someString` returns an `int id` referencing that `String`. You would need `getString(R.id.someString)` to get the `String` value.

I don't mean to sound rude but you seriously need to go through this piece-by-piece and look at the Java docs and learn Java a little better or you are going to have a heck of a time learning Android. Also, if you post only what you think is most relevant then more people will look at it. I'm sure I could find a lot more but I don't want to go through every piece of your code. We can always kindly ask for more code when we think its relevant.

Comment: Also, his `getPersonality()` method is comparing Strings with two incorrect approaches.

Comment: I tried .get() and .equals...not sure what to do from there

Comment: @A--C Thanks, I have edited to include that.